# How to force the right six-column DIV to stay on top in RWD?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a custom 12-column grid and given a row like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="the-pink" class="lg-6 md-12 sm-12"><!-- content --></div>
    <div id="the-violet" class="lg-6 md-12 sm-12"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
```

[image: Large device layout]

I'm trying to get this behaviour: On medium and small devices each block will be 12-columns width but, by default, `#the-violet` will fall below `#the-pink`. I'd like the opposite, that's `#the-violet` above `#the-pink`.

[image: Natural vs Desired layout]

My current *(simplified)* SCCS is:

```
.row {
    @include clearfix;
    [class*="lg-"],
    [class*="md-"],
    [class*="sm-"] {
        float: left;
    }
}
.lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.md-12 {
    @include respond-to("medium") {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.sm-12 {
    @include respond-to("small") {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

*I'm assuming `clearfix` and `respond-to` mixins are well-known.*

I've made and approach with fixed height giving my row a class named `reversed` like ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/rn7b77f0/1/)):

```
.reversed {
    position: relative;
    @include respond-to("small" "medium") {
        .sm-12,
        .md-12 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            &::first-child {
                top: 200px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I'd like to know if anyone has faced this need before and has another approach to solve it in a *clean* way (without fixing height).

Comment: Bootstrap uses pull & push classes that does this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Paulie_D! I've found this [article](http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/) explaining this concept. I knew about `push` classes but not about `pull` ones. I'll digg into it to implement this solution on my grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float: right` on them and write them in the reverse order in the HTML.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! It's really a simple option... anyway I'd prefer a pure CSS solution.